# Customise hyperlinks in aem/cq

Tags: adobe, aem, rte

The following link shows RichtextEditor using Links

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/using_rich_text_editor.html#Links

My requirement is I need to customise Hyperlink or I need to customise rich text editor so that I need a button like mailto:

so on clicking that button I can have a text box to enter the email address.

I have found that one needs to customise the extjs of rte pluigins, but not sure what I need to? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "HTML rules" node inside the richtext xtype of your dialog.xml. Add a "Links" node as a child of this & you can configure the allowed protocols:

```
<text
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="richtext">
    <htmlRules 
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <links
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            protocols="[http://,https://,mailto:]"/>
    </htmlRules>
</text>
```

Comment: No this is not I want..this I already have..what i need is i need to add a new button in rich text editor and on its click link dialog should come with a textbox and on entering teh text in  textbox it should be able to append with mailto:

Comment: Ah, I see! You need to register a plugin via ExtJs alright & then include when configuring your RTE. The code would be far too involved to show here, but [this blog post is a good intro](http://experience-aem.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/aem-cq-56-extend-richtext-editor-add-new-plugin-pullquote.html) to coding up a plugin. You could start from the default link plugin also & overlay into your apps folder, as it may be nearer to what you need.

Comment: I tried the above link and it works well...now on cliking the button pull quote functionality comes how can I make it to extend link plugin so that i need <a href="mailto:test@stackoverflow.co.uk" ></a> to work where from code i will appending mailto and the user needs to enter only his email id.